# Temperature reading

Tags: c

HELPPPPPP......This is my code for temperature reading input by the user but I really not sure what is wrong with my code. When I compile it says "expected expression before 'else' ".I need help, Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>

   main()
   {
   double lowest = 38;
   double temp;
   char bpower;

   printf("Enter temperature(C):");
   scanf("%lf", &temp);

   if(temp<lowest)
   {

     lowest = temp;

   }

     printf("Backup power on? (Y/N):");
     fflush(stdin);
     scanf("%c", &bpower);

    if(temp < 50);
    {

    printf("Normal mode of operation\n");
    printf("Continue to read the next temperature\n");

    }

    else

    {

       if(temp < 80)

       {
        printf("Turn on circulating fan\n");
        printf("Continue to read the next temperature\n");

       }


       else

       {
         if(bpower == 'N')   



        {
        printf("Turn off equipment\n");
        printf("Lowest temperature is %.2f", lowest);

        }

        else

        {  

         printf("Continue to read the next temperature\n");

         }

      }



 }
}
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` - this has undefined behaviour

Comment: `if(temp < 50);` -- Look carefully here.

Comment: Could do with tidying up the indentation of the code - do you need so many blank lines

Comment: Indentation dude... It's important

Comment: Could do with checking the return values of `scanf`

Comment: The behaviour of this code would have been much more obvious if you have stepped through it, line-by-line.  Your very next step in learning software develpment, one that is already overdue, it to find out how to use a debugger.  Don't write any more code until you have, at least minimal, debugging skills.

Answer (score 2):

You have a stray semicolon in one of your `if` statements.  Change this:

```
if(temp < 50);
{

printf("Normal mode of operation\n");
printf("Continue to read the next temperature\n");

}
```

to this:

```
if(temp < 50)
{

printf("Normal mode of operation\n");
printf("Continue to read the next temperature\n");

}
```